# TypeScript: Loop through properties of Class with Object.keys(this)

Tags: typescript

I want to loop through the properties of a class to generate a json representation.

`Object.keys(this).forEach((key: keyof MyElement)` always throws a error: 
`Argument of type '(key: "name" | "toJSON") => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'key' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type "name" | "toJSON"'.`

How can I solve this?

Here is the class.

```
export class MyElement {

    private _name: string = '';

    get name(): string {
        return this._name;
    }

    set name(value: string) {
        this._name = value;
    }

    public toJSON = (): Object => {

        let json = {};

        Object.keys(this).forEach((key: keyof MyElement) => {  // Error: TS2345: Argument of type '(key: "name" | "toJSON") => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => void'.
        // Types of parameters 'key' and 'value' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type "name" | "toJSON"'.

            const val = this[key];

            if (typeof val !== "function") {

                let newKey = key[0] === '_' ? key.slice(1) : key;
                json[newKey] = val;
            }
        });

        return json;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the lambda's signature to something that's compatible with `forEach`'s signature:

```
Object.keys(this).forEach((key: string) => {
    // ...
})
```

Based on the code you've shown, there's no real benefit to using the artificial `key: keyof MyElement`, so just use a signature that TypeScript will like.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there's no way for the compiler to know that the only keys returned by `forEach` are also keys of `MyElement`. For example you could define a new class that extends `MyElement` and has additional keys, or you could have updated it with `Object.assign()`.

So you have to make `forEach` take a string parameter and perform appropriate casting when you try to access `this[key]` (otherwise if you have `--noImplicitAny` compiler option set you will get an error as the result of subscripting is implicitly `any`). Also `json` will need an index signature to let you assign it arbitrary attributes.

```
public toJSON = (): Object => {

    let json: { [key: string]: string } = {};

    Object.keys(this).forEach((key: string) => { 
        const val = (this as any)[key];
        if (typeof val !== "function") {

            let newKey = key[0] === '_' ? key.slice(1) : key;
            json[newKey] = val;
        }
    });

    return json;
}
```

Comment: @JLRishe if you compile with `--strict` which implies no implicit any then `const val = this[key]` will give an error `error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'MyElement' has no index signature.`

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying that.